# Installation of FreeDOS on a hard disk

Tags: linux, freedos

I have some questions about the installation of FreeDOS on a hard disk. I was not able to find the responses on the pages of freedos.org.

I'm starting with the file FD12CD.iso and I'm running Linux.

Can I use a FAT16 partition on any hard disk ? Is a primary partition necessary ? Have this partition to be the first primary partition ? Can I use a GPT partitioned disk ? Can I copy the FD12CD.iso to the partition on the hard disk using the dd utility ?

Any other problems to handle here ?

Comment: Some of your questions can be answered by simple experiments.

Answer (score 1):

My answer may quickly appear to be rather dated as it appears vague on some points, but since the question is young (I'm responding within the hour), I thought it may be helpful.  (I might or might not end up updating this.)

> Can I use a FAT16 partition on any hard disk ?

MS-DOS supports FAT12 and FAT16 with partitions up to 2 GB.  FreeDOS supports the same, and I believe FreeDOS also handles FAT32 partitions fine, at least up to disks of about 120 GB.  If you get disks above that, you can have problems unless the software supports LBA 48.  I don't readily recall if that's the case.

https://web.archive.org/web/20180609115505/http://wiki.freedos.org/wiki/index.php/UEFI

notes, "Hard disk manufacturers are already (2010 and later) coming out with hard disks with large sectors, which BIOS does not handle (they are hard-coded to 512-byte sectors)."

> Is a primary partition necessary ?

For Traditional DOS, yes.  FreeDOS is more flexible about some things.  I don't recall if it supports booting off of a "logical drive" (within an extended partition).

> Have this partition to be the first primary partition ?

No.  That is not a requirement of any operating system that I've heard of.

> Can I use a GPT partitioned disk ?

Apparently not.  GPT is often tied to UEFI support (rather unnecessarily, but commonly).  For further info about UEFI, perhaps check out:

http://wiki.freedos.org/wiki/index.php/Releases/1.3#Support_for_UEFI.3F
and/or
http://wiki.freedos.org/wiki/index.php/UEFI
although at the moment, both currently show me:

"Project Website Temporarily Offline"
"SourceForge project websites are currently experiencing abnormally high levels of traffic. Our support staff has been notified."

https://web.archive.org/web/20200519145614/http://wiki.freedos.org/wiki/index.php/Releases/1.3#UEFI
shows "Since Intel plans to end "legacy BIOS" support in their new platforms by 2020 (in favor of UEFI) users have asked if FreeDOS will be updated to support UEFI. The short answer is No."

https://web.archive.org/web/20180609115505/http://wiki.freedos.org/wiki/index.php/UEFI

also denies any plans for that.

> Can I copy the FD12CD.iso to the partition on the hard disk using the dd utility ?

Yes, but probably uselessly so.  The point of the ISO file is to try booting it.  From there, run the installer, which is likely to use XFDisk to create partitions, FORMAT to create a FAT filesystem onto a partition, and SYS which copies over the system files and updates the boot code in the MBR.

You can often do much of that manually with other tools.  Precise requirements vary with DOS versions.  I do suggest copying the *io* file (IBMBIO.SYS in most DOS's, but IO.SYS in MS-DOS) as the first file on the drive, followed by the other file (IBMCOM.SYS in most DOS's, MSDOS.SYS in MS-DOS), and perhaps your command line interpreter (the excellent 4DOS 7.50.1 is recommended for FreeDOS, or perhaps a newer version, but COMMAND.COM bundled with FreeDOS may also work).

> Any other problems to handle here ?

This "question" in SuperUser violates our recommended format here on Stack Exchange.  Each "question" page on SuperUser is meant to focus on just one question.  When you have multiple questions like this, the preferred route is to create one "question" page for each question.

The reason for that is so that we don't have a problem where some answers end up answering some questions better than others.  Just limiting one question per page helps things flow more smoothly.

For newer systems, the items of common concern that I've encountered are support for large disks, and support for more RAM.  As I recall, MS-DOS could have troubles on systems with 2GB or even 1.5 GB of RAM.  (I don't offhand recall how well FreeDOS handles larger-RAM systems.)

You'll also want to make sure an X64 system is booting into the mode that enables 16-bit code.  Using a 16-bit kernel will likely work with that.  If you end up running in 64-bit enhanced mode, you'll get some superior speed and other benefits of a 64-bit chip but will lose 16-bit compatibility in that mode, typically until you reboot.  Losing 16-bit compatibility will essentially eliminate compatibility with many, many pieces of software for DOS (including parts of the operating system itself).